# Why can't I call new from within a static method?

Tags: java, methods, static

I have some utility functions that I've declared as `static`, as they are not to be instantiated, only used for utilities. I would like to create a generator method that can generate objects, but in the same `static` utility context.

```
public class PeerConnection {

    public class _Heartbeat{
        protected String beat = "HB_000";
        protected String ack  = "HB_001";
        protected String msg  = null;

        protected Date beatTime = null;
        protected Date ackTime  = null;
        protected short missedBeats = 0;
        protected short MAX_MISS = 3;
    }

    public _Heartbeat heartbeat = null;
    //map of heartbeat objects per Peer connection
    public static List<_Heartbeat> Heartbeats = new ArrayList<_Heartbeat>();

    public static void GenerateHeartbeat(){
        Heartbeats.add(new _Heartbeat());
    }
```

My reasoning, is I want to call this from a `SendHeartbeat` method:

```
   private static int SendHeartbeat(PeerConnection peer){
        int acks = 0;
        PeerConnection.GenerateHeartbeat();
        PeerConnection._Heartbeat hb = peer.Heartbeats.get(peer.Heartbeats.size() - 1);
        hb.msg = hb.beat;

        while (acks <= 0 && hb.missedBeats < hb.MAX_MISS){
         [...]
        }
   }
```

I get the concept of why static works this way, but I'm thinking there has to be a work around for this scenario.

Comment: Try `public static class _Heartbeat {` ...

Comment: Make the inner class static ... check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Answer (score 2):

`_Heatbeat` is not a static class, so any instance of it is explicitly tied to an instance of the `PeerConnection` class. I.e. to instantiate `_Heartbeat` you need an instance of the `PeerConnection` class.

One option is to make `_Heartbeat` a static class (i.e. `public static class _Heartbeat`, which I think is probably what you want.

Another option is to instantiate both together  like this `new PeerConnection().new _Heartbeat()` (I saw this in the java certification exam, but I hate it and never use it so I may not be remembering the syntax correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You need an actual object of your Peer class to instannciate the inner class as this class belongs to an object. Just simply as that...

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation : nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

I think your question is more about nested classes than static stuff.
Give back to Caesar what is Caesar's :  [A realy good answer to your problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70358/4088809)

So in your case you have two option :

```
 public static class _Heartbeat{ ... }
```

or

```
public static void GenerateHeartbeat(PeerConnection p){
    Heartbeats.add(p.new _Heartbeat());
}

private static int SendHeartbeat(PeerConnection peer){
    int acks = 0;
    PeerConnection.GenerateHeartbeat(peer);
    PeerConnection._Heartbeat hb = peer.Heartbeats.get(peer.Heartbeats.size() - 1);
    hb.msg = hb.beat;

    while (acks <= 0 && hb.missedBeats < hb.MAX_MISS){
     [...]
    }
}
```